# How to implement a Central Authentication Server in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement a **Authentication Server** using ***Django*** which will be used only for user authentication.
We have multiple services hosted on different subdomains like *one.service.com*, *two.service.com*, *three.service.com* etc. And we don't want our users to memorize/use different login credentials for each service. We want a system where user can authenticate themselves through the auth server and can access all the services of the subdomains.

Just think about **Google** or **Microsoft**, we just need one login credential and then we can access all of their services.

How can I implement this type of system for our services using **Django** ??

Note: We are primarily using **JWTAuthentication** for our servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSO with [SimpleJWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/experimental_features.html) is the best and easier approach.
in Django settings set [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) to all subdomains use cookies and save tokens on that

check links for detail